# Password Manager for Ubuntu with ports available for android

Tags: password, android

I need a password manager for Ubuntu (a program in which I can save all my password like site access, credit card codes, software licenses, etc.) that has also a version for android in order to have the passwords synchronized between devices. Something like [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword). Does anybody knows such a program?

Answer (score 1):

[KeepassX](http://www.keepassx.org/) is a frontend for Keepass and there are various Keepass apps for Android. You can put the Keepass database on Dropbox or a similar online storage to share it between platforms.

Answer (score 1):

There are several password managing softwares/services out there.

**FOSS and Offline**

- [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)
- [KeepassX](https://www.keepassx.org) (a Contributed/Unofficial KeePass Port)

**Subscription based:**

- [LastPass](https://lastpass.com)

I personally use keepass and sync it using Dropbox and USB. But You can use Lastpass to avoid the hassle of syncing the database files.